# Kubernetes sidecar with debug tools

Tags: kubernetes, .net-core, sidecar

I'm trying to introduce a sidecar with dotnet debug tools
According to this
https://thecloudblog.net/post/tracing-and-profiling-a-net-core-application-on-azure-kubernetes-service-with-a-sidecar-container/
Doing the below command should work

```
kubectl debug <SOME-POD>  -n <SOME NAMESPACE> --image=<NET_IMAGE_WITH_TOOLS> --copy-to=debug-pod --share-processes --tty --stdin --container=debug
```

But when I run commands inside the container shell

```
dotnet-counters  ps
```

I see no dotnet processes?

Im sure I am using same dotnet runtimes across all images

Unsure if other Istio sidecars affect it but tried to manually run a pod without it and I dont believe it helped.